# Using Entity Framework 6 with SQL Server Compact 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce-4

I'm trying to create a SQL Server Compact database from the code using code-first scenario, utilizing Entity Framework. Everything worked until I realized I have installed SQL Server 2014 Express and it was using it (instead of local `.sdf` file, which is what I'm looking for). Therefore, I uninstalled SQL Server 2014 Express.

Now, in my solution, I'm using `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact` nuget extension.

However, whenever I try to initialize `DbContext`, I get error:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)"

I tried setting up connection string in the `app.config` to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompactDBContext"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
         connectionString="MyDatabase.sdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Or setting it in the code, passing it into `DbContext` constructor, different variations of the connection string, etc...

This is the DbContext declaration:

```cs
 public class CompactDBContext : DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }
 }
```

And this is how I'm using it:

```cs
public void InsertItem()
{
    using (var db = new CompactDBContext())
    {
        MyItem item = new MyItem();

        db.MyItems.Add(item);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is either duplicate question or I'm missing something really trivial, but I spent hours figuring this out without any luck.

Can someone please point to right direction?

**Update 1:**

By using DbContext constructor with SqlCeConnection as parameter:

```cs
public CompactDBContext() : 
  base(new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"),
  contextOwnsConnection: true) { }
```

I'm getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No Entity Framework provider found for the
>   ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'.
>   Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section
>   of the application config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Comment: How are you *initializing the dbcontext*?

Comment: Could you share the Entity Framework related sections from app.config, you are still connection to SQL Server

Comment: @ErikEJ: Added code snippets and app.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling with the solution and project, I found out the reason. In my setup, my application is library, and I was testing it from UnitTest project. For some reason I by mistake unloaded app.config from the UnitTest project, therefore it was complaing about missing EntityFramework providers. Loading app.confing back into project fixed the problem.

Comment: Class library projects will use the main project app.config. How did you unload the app config from your unit test project?

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have installed System.Data.SqlServerCE.dll in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Private

if not you must install before SSCERuntime-ENU.msi from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=17876